# Make this layout responsive without duplicate elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, responsive

I have to create this layout responsive for a custom slider:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScES5.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfuET.jpg

-The icon of an image is where the slides are going to be.

-There is another pink block with the controls of the slider.

-The last pink block has some text. Nothing special.

There are 2 background-images in those patterns.

I began with the desktop version using flexbox, **but when I try to adjust the layout to the tablet version,** it was imposible because this two elements are in different rows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1luW.jpg

This is more or less my code right now:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <img class="logo-img"
                     src="assets/images/logo.png">
                <div class="titulo-boton">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <div class="row primera" primera>
                    <div class="col yourtrip">
                        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                        <hr>
                        <p class="tags">#tags</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col"></div>

                    <div class="col ">
                        <div class="image-slider image-wrap">
                            <!--                            <img src="assets/images/rocket.png">-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" segunda>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col controls" controls>
                        <div class="botones row w-100">
                            <div class="col p-0">
                                <a href="#" class="btn">prev</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col p-0">
                                <a href="#" class="btn">next</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

I have created a pen to make the things easier. The assets are different but the layout is the same.

https://codepen.io/jenvigo/pen/jRrwdw?editors=1100

Comment: Were gonna need to see your css

Comment: @Hybrid thanks for your response. I have edited the post with a codepen link.

Comment: Maybe using css grid?